# Python3 : How to print all diagonals with fixed length in a matrix

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, tic-tac-toe

I'm currently working on a Tic-Tac-Toe project. I want the board to have custom size. But I have no idea how to check all the rows, columns and diagonals with a fixed length of k (k is customizable). Here an example to clarify what I meant.

```
"""
For example if the board is a 4x4 matrix and I want to check the rows, cols, and diagonals of consecutive cells with fixed length of 3
"""
board = [[1, 2, 3, 4]
         [5, 6, 7, 8]
         [9, 10,11,12]
         [13,14,15,16]]
# Print all rows:
# Output: [1,2,3], [2,3,4], [5,6,7], [6,7,8], [9,10,11], [10,11,12], [13,14,15], [14,15,16]

# Print all cols:
# Output: [1,5,9], [5,9,13], [2,6,10], [6,10,14], [3,7,11], [7,11,15], [4,8,12], [8,12,16]

# Print all diagonals (beside 2 main diagonals there're more smaller diagonals):
# Output: [1,6,11], [6,11,16], [4,7,10], [7,10,13], [3,6,9], [2,7,12], [5,10,15], [8,11,14]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working pice of code with explanation. There's multiple ways to tackle this, and the way you choose will depend on how you are gonna use this code. I chose to create generators that iterate over the board.

```py
import numpy as np
board = np.array( [
    [1, 2 ,3 ,4 ],
    [5, 6 ,7 ,8 ],
    [9, 10,11,12],
    [13,14,15,16]
    ])
```

To make it easier to iterate over the board itself, I made it into a `numpy` array, so that iterating over columns is as straightforward as it is to iterate over rows, and so is checking dimensions and such.

The core pice of code you need is really simple: pass a row, column or diagonal to this function and a desired size, and it will yield sub-lists of size until it no longer can.

```py
def get_sublist(line, size):
    i = 0
    length = len(line)
    while i<=length-size:
        yield line[i:i+size]
        i+=1
```

Then all you need to do to get the rows or columns is iterate over the board or the transposed board like so:

```py
#for rows
for line in board:
    yield from get_sublist(line, size)

#for columns
for line in board.T
    yield from get_sublist(line, size)
```

Finally, to iterate over diagonals you can use the handy `numpy.diag` function and do the exact same. For the antidiagonals, just flip the array:

```py
    #get the diagonals
    for d in range(-size, size+1):
        yield from get_sublist(np.diag(board, d), size)
    
    #get antidiagonals
    board = np.fliplr(board)
    for d in range(-size, size+1):
        yield from get_sublist(np.diag(board, d), size)
```

All in all, the full working code is as follows. I added a few checks so that you don't get unexpected errors. I hope you learnt some things from this!

```py
import numpy as np
board = np.array( [
    [1, 2 ,3 ,4 ],
    [5, 6 ,7 ,8 ],
    [9, 10,11,12],
    [13,14,15,16]
    ])


def get_sublist(line, size):
    i = 0
    length = len(line)
    while i<=length-size:
        yield line[i:i+size]
        i+=1            
    

def get_line(board, size, column=True):
    """Get sub-sections of rows or columns of board up to given size. column 
    decides if it iterates over rows or columns"""
    
    if not isinstance(column, bool):
        raise TypeError(f'row should be type bool, not {type(column)}')
    
    if size > board.shape[column]:
        raise ValueError(f'Cant get size {size} rows, board is {board.shape}')
    
    if column: 
        board = board.T
        
    for line in board:
        yield from get_sublist(line, size)
    
        
def get_diags(board, size):
    """Get sub-sections of the diagonals of the board for the given size"""
     
    if size > board.shape[0]:
        raise ValueError(f'Cant get size {size} rows, board is {board.shape}')
  
    #get the diagonals
    for d in range(-size, size+1):
        yield from get_sublist(np.diag(board, d), size)
    
    #get antidiagonals
    board = np.fliplr(board)
    for d in range(-size, size+1):
        yield from get_sublist(np.diag(board, d), size)
    

print(list(get_line(board, 3, column=True)))
print(list(get_line(board, 3, column=False)))
print(lies(get_diags(board, 3)))
```